# Use native components that not provided by RN team

Tags: react-native

Is there anyway to use native components that not provided by the RN team? For example UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely! It's a bit more work, but essentially what you will be doing is creating a [Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html), which is essentially what all the built-in React Native components are. Essentially, you need to create a bridge between Javascript and the native Objective-C (or Swift) code. You can also do this with components you build yourself in Objective C/Swift, not just the default native iOS ones.

Comment: Thank's. This approach is required good knowledge of ObjectiveC, but I don't know about it :(